# Update People picker column using REST API in Power Automate

Tags: sharepoint-online, sharepoint-rest-api, people-picker, flow, power-automate

How to update people picker column using REST API in Power Automate?

I have three people picker column in SharePoint.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Using REST API, You can update People or Group field by setting field with user or group ID.

Considering field name is `AssignedTo`, the format for user field value:

Single-valued user field: `'AssignedToId' : 1`

Multi-valued user field: `'AssignedToId' : { 'results': [1, 2, 3] }`

Where 1, 2, 3 are ID of users/groups.

**Example**:

[image]

**References**:

1. [Update a people field in a SharePoint List using REST API using Power Automate](https://sharepains.com/2018/07/02/people-field-rest-api-power-automate/)
2. [HOW TO UPDATE THE SHAREPOINT PEOPLE PICKER FIELD USING POWER AUTOMATE](https://jobs.collab365.community/how-to-update-the-sharepoint-people-picker-field-using-power-automate/)

Comment: how to get this numeric id dynamic, if i have people picker value from file property and want to update it

Comment: what value you have from file property? Check [this](https://sharepains.com/2019/12/17/get-the-user-id-to-update-a-people-field-in-sharepoint-with-power-automate/) or [this](https://powerusers.microsoft.com/t5/Building-Flows/How-to-return-a-user-ID-using-flow/td-p/342934) to get user ID if you know user email address.

Answer (score 1):

You could choose to use Update Item action in flow.

1. [Set a people field in SharePoint with Power Automate when all you have is a user’s name.](https://sharepains.com/2018/11/05/microsoft-flow-set-a-people-field-in-sharepoint-when-all-you-have-is-a-users-name/)
2. [FLOW UPDATE MULTI-SELECT COLUMN](https://wonderlaura.com/2020/09/01/flow-update-multi-select-column/)

If you have got the user information in the previous actions, you could find them here.
[image]