# Add a people value to a SharePoint Online list using the email address

Tags: sharepoint-online, permissions, sharepoint-rest-api, user-profile, person-or-group

Using SOAP Services, we used to be able to add multiple items in a list that contains a people field just using the email address and without knowing the user id. In that case the value to provide was `-1;#email@address`.

Example of a SOAP body to send:

```
<Field Name='ID'>New</Field><Field Name='Title'>Example</Field><Field Name='Name'>-1;#user@domain.com</Field></Method>
```

It was very handy because we could add 50 items in 1 call.

**I'm trying to do the same thing in SharePoint Online, without using SOAP services. It could be either REST or Graph.**

So far I found that I need to first use [ensureUser](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/previous-versions/office/sharepoint-visio/jj245233(v=office.15)?redirectedfrom=MSDN) to get the user id for each email address, and then add the items using that user id… So instead of doing 1 call to add 50 items, I have to do 50 calls to get the user id, and then 50 more calls to add them (I may reduce the number of calls using the `$batch` but I'm not sure it can work with `ensureUser`).

Is there any other way to directly add a user using an email address to SPO?

Answer (score 0):

If users you are trying to add to people field are already added to your SharePoint site (collection), you can use below API call to get all users & their email/user id using **single** API call:

```
https://<tenant>.sharepoint.com/sites/<siteName>/_api/web/siteusers?$select=Title,Email,Id
```

You can compare the email addresses you have with the response from above API call & get the user IDs you need for next API call.

If you don't find any user (email address) in the response from above API call, you have to use the `ensureUser()` method to add particular user to SharePoint site ("User Information List").

---

After getting all user IDs you need, you can set people field with multiple users using **single** API call like below:

- Considering field name is `AssignedTo`, the format for people field value in your payload should be like:

```
data: JSON.stringify({
        "__metadata": { type: "SP.Data.PostsListItem" },
        "AssignedToId": { 'results': [1, 2, 3] }
      })
```

Where 1, 2, 3 are ID of users.

For more information on this, check my answer given at: [Update People picker column using REST API in Power Automate](https://sharepoint.stackexchange.com/questions/289066/update-people-picker-column-using-rest-api-in-power-automate/289067#289067)

Comment: Thanks. It's not multiple users in one field, but 1 user by entry. With 150,000 entries (with unique users) to add in a list. They are not in the SiteUsers list yet… I ended using the SOAP service to do it. Quick & easy.

Comment: If you are trying to create multiple entries/rows in list, you have to batch the multiple requests to add/update the entries in list.